# Redirect to another page after a page with a pdf file displays for 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, asp.net-ajax

please I'm having a hard time getting this to work. I'm fairly new to MVC.

So here is my challenge.
I have an actionResult in my controller that reads a pdf file and displays the pdf in a browser:`

```
public ActionResult ViewPdf(DocumentSearchInputModel searchInputModel)
        {
            var realPath =
                     "C:/Users/ionyejekwe/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/OnlineSearchLagos/OnlineSearchLagos/assets/img/gtb.pdf";
            var fileStream = new FileStream(realPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
            return File(fsResult, "application/pdf");
        }`
```

In a view called searchResult.cshtm, I have this
`<a  href="@Url.Action("ViewPdf", "Search", Model)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">View pdf</a>`

which is supposed to call the pdf actionResult and render it to the browser.
It works perfectly fine. But I want to close the pdf page, after 5 minutes. I have tried many ways, but none seems to be working.
I tried using this ajax:`

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ViewPdf", "Search")',
        contentType: "application/pdf; charset=utf-8",
        success: function() { alert('Success'); },
        error: function () { alert('A error'); }
    });

</script>`
```

just to see if the ajax will get to the page, but the ajax code its not even getting to the pdf page, it's been triggered in the page where the pdf is being called. Please how do i get the pdf page to close or redirect to another page after 5 minutes.
I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try it with the `window.open()` function. It opens a new tab with the first parameter as its URL. I have no experience with ASP so I am not trying to get the URL of your PDF.

```
var newWindow = window.open("your_url_here");
setTimeout(function(){newWindow.close()}, 300000);
```

what this will do is open a new tab with the PDF and close it after 300000ms = 5min.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user8107351 where you have your AJAX call right now